# Mybatis Custom function

Tags: database, mybatis

I work with Mybatis and I want to write this sql

```
begin;
   drop table if exists production.mindia;
   select * into production.mindia from staging.mindia
commit;
```

but there are only insert,update .... tag

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a stored procedure with your SQL code and call it in mybatis with a select statement and put the result in a resultmap:

```
<resultMap type="State" id="resultState">
    <result property="id" column="state_id"/>
    <result property="name" column="state_name"/>
    <result property="code" column="state_code"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="callGetStates" resultMap="resultState" statementType="CALLABLE">
    { CALL getStates()}
</select>
```

The blog from Loiane Groner has some really nice tutorials for MyBatis (http://loianegroner.com/?s=mybatis) including one about stored procedures. 
You should take a look at this!